# PHP+HTML Table Horizontal While Loop

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I am building a weather website and working on a custom forecast page. I have a database setup on the server for the values. Here is what I have for the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM forecast ORDER BY FID";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$i = 0;

echo '<table width="1400" border="1">';
echo '<td>';
while ($forecast = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<table width="200" border="1">';
        echo '<tr>';
    echo "<th colspan='4'>{$forecast['DAY']}</th>";
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td height='100' width='100' colspan='2'>ICON</td>";
    echo "<td height='100' width='100' colspan='2'>ROSE</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$forecast['HIGH']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$forecast['LOW']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$forecast['WIND']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$forecast['GUST']}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>Precip:{$forecast['RAIN']}</td>";
    echo "<td>Severe:{$forecast['SEVERE']} </td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    ++$i;
}
echo '</td>';
echo '</table>';
```

But when I run that, I don't get a horizontal layout like I want (The loop makes a table that shows the forecast, and I want 7 in a row) but I get a vertical layout. See photo: http://www.themacvortex.com/TableFail.png

How can I modify my code to get horizontal layout?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML.

Comment: Here is the result http://themacvortex.com/forecastdisplay.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the outer `<table>` with a single `<td>` with a missing surrounding `<tr>`. But the real problem is this:

Your outer `<td>` should read `<tr>`. And your `while` should read like this:

```
while ($forecast = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo '<td>'
      . '<table width="200" border="1">'
      . ..... more ...
      . '</table>'
      . '</td>
      ;
}
```

The  inside the `while` creates new columns during each `while` iteration.

[W3C's validation service](http://validator.w3.org) might probably helpful too.